# Page numbering roman and arabic report document

Tags: numbering

I'm editing my dissertation and I need to number pages 2 through 5 (up to table of contents) using roman numerals, then restart numbering using arabic numbers for the entirety of the document. As the code stands numbering starts at page 5 and I can't make it work the way I need despite my efforts.

Here's the code

```
\documentclass[reqno,12pt,oneside]{report}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[top=1in, bottom=1in, left=1.5in, right=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[singlespacing]{setspace}
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{endnotes}
\usepackage{graphicx, subfigure}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.eps,.jpg}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[tableposition=top]{caption}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{subfigure}  
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{color, colortbl}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\definecolor{Gray}{gray}{0.9}
\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}
\usepackage{array,longtable,calc}
\newcommand{\ra}[1]{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{#1}}
\usepackage{arydshln}
\usepackage[margin=65pt,font=small,labelfont=bf,justification=raggedright,singlelinecheck=false]{caption}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[backend=biber,authordate,natbib,maxnames=2,minnames=1]{biblatex-chicago}

\renewcommand*{\nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\addspace}



\addbibresource{bibliography_compiled.bib}
\usepackage{hyperref}



\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{acknowledgement}{Acknowledgement}
\newtheorem{algorithm}[theorem]{Algorithm}
\newtheorem{axiom}[theorem]{Axiom}
\newtheorem{case}[theorem]{Case}
\newtheorem{claim}[theorem]{Claim}
\newtheorem{conclusion}[theorem]{Conclusion}
\newtheorem{condition}[theorem]{Condition}
\newtheorem{conjecture}[theorem]{Conjecture}
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{criterion}[theorem]{Criterion}
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}
\newtheorem{example}[theorem]{Example}
\newtheorem{exercise}[theorem]{Exercise}
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{notation}[theorem]{Notation}
\newtheorem{problem}[theorem]{Problem}
\newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}
\newtheorem{remark}[theorem]{Remark}
\newtheorem{solution}[theorem]{Solution}
\newtheorem{summary}[theorem]{Summary}
\newenvironment{proof}[1][Proof]{\noindent\textbf{#1.} }{\ \rule{0.5em}{0.5em}}
\makeatletter
\makeatother
\geometry{left=1in,right=1in,top=1.00in,bottom=1.0in}
%\setcounter{secnumdepth}{2}

\makeatletter
\if@twoside \setcounter{page}{4} \else \setcounter{page}{2} \fi
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\begin{titlepage}
\vspace*{\fill}


\begin{center}

{\Large\uppercase{\bfseries Title of Dissertation}}

\vspace{6.25cm}
{First Last Name} \\ [5pt]
\vspace{4cm}
{Submitted to the faculty of the University Graduate School}\\[5pt]
{in partial fulfillment of the requirement for the degree}\\[5pt]
{Doctor of Philosophy}\\[5pt]
{in the Department of Economics,}\\[5pt]
\vfill
{July 2015}
\end{center}
\end{titlepage}



\begin{titlepage}

\renewcommand{\thepage}{\roman{page}}

\begin{center}

{Accepted by the Graduate Faculty in partial\\
fulfillment of the requirements for the degree of Doctor of\\
Philosophy}\\[8cm]


\raggedright{ Doctoral Committee}
\vspace{1cm}

\raggedleft{\makebox[2.5in]{\hrulefill}}\\
\raggedleft{Committee Member 1, Ph.D.\\[1.5cm]

\makebox[2.5in]{\hrulefill}\\
\raggedleft{Committee Member 2, Ph.D.}\\[1.5cm]

\makebox[2.5in]{\hrulefill}\\
\raggedleft{Committee Member 3, Ph.D.}\\[1.5cm]

\makebox[2.5in]{\hrulefill}\\
\raggedleft{Committee Member 4, Ph.D.}\\[1.5cm]


\raggedright{July 21st, 2015}
\end{titlepage}

\begin{titlepage}
\begin{center}
\vspace*{\fill}

Copyright \copyright \, \the\year\\
\vspace{0.5cm}
{Name} \\ [5pt]
\end{center}
\end{titlepage}

\begin{titlepage}
\vspace{4cm}

\begin{center}

\centering{First Last Name\\ \vspace{0.5cm}
\centering{\uppercase{Title}}\\ 

\vspace{1cm}

\justify
This paper examines ...
\vspace{1cm}

\raggedleft{\makebox[2in]{\hrulefill}}\\
\raggedleft{Committee Member 1, Ph.D.}\\[0.7cm]

\makebox[2in]{\hrulefill}\\
\raggedleft{Committee Member 2 Ph.D.}\\[0.7cm]

\makebox[2in]{\hrulefill}\\
\raggedleft{Committee Member 3, Ph.D.}\\[0.7cm]

\makebox[2in]{\hrulefill}\\
\raggedleft{Committee Member 4, Ph.D.}\\[0.7cm]

\end{center}
\end{titlepage}


\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}




\tableofcontents

\pagenumbering{arabic}
\input{chapter1}

\input{chapter2}

\input{chapter3}



\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\frontmatter`... `\mainmatter` with the `book` class would be ideal. You should know that your code contains many things which it should not and that the results you get will not be of especially good typographical quality. You are also likely to run into frustrating and deeply puzzling weirdnesses which may take you a lot of time and energy to semi-fix. However, it is a thesis and typography is not, therefore, very important, so if your institution accepts it this way, don't change it. Just don't code like this usually ;).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need it automatic, you could've used the `book` class as pointed out by @cfr in a comment. In which case you simply say `\frontmatter` and Roman numbering begins then you say `\mainmatter` and Arabic numbering begins. You are using too many packages that I suspect will be useful and may have many incompatibilities, so I recommend starting from scratch (If your institution does't provide a template) and adding only the packages you need.

The main problem in your case, however, is that you defined more than one `titlepage` and a `titlepage` does not have a page number, that is why the command `\pagenumbering{roman}` didn't work. So, simply remove all `titlepage`s but the first one and your code will work.

```
\documentclass[reqno,12pt,oneside]{report}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[top=1in, bottom=1in, left=1.5in, right=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[singlespacing]{setspace}
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{endnotes}
\usepackage{graphicx, subfigure}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.eps,.jpg}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[tableposition=top]{caption}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{subfigure,lipsum}  
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{color, colortbl}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\definecolor{Gray}{gray}{0.9}
\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}
\usepackage{array,longtable,calc}
\newcommand{\ra}[1]{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{#1}}
\usepackage{arydshln}
\usepackage[margin=65pt,font=small,labelfont=bf,justification=raggedright,singlelinecheck=false]{caption}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[backend=biber,authordate,natbib,maxnames=2,minnames=1]{biblatex-chicago}

\renewcommand*{\nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\addspace}

\addbibresource{bibliography_compiled.bib}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{acknowledgement}{Acknowledgement}
\newtheorem{algorithm}[theorem]{Algorithm}
\newtheorem{axiom}[theorem]{Axiom}
\newtheorem{case}[theorem]{Case}
\newtheorem{claim}[theorem]{Claim}
\newtheorem{conclusion}[theorem]{Conclusion}
\newtheorem{condition}[theorem]{Condition}
\newtheorem{conjecture}[theorem]{Conjecture}
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{criterion}[theorem]{Criterion}
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}
\newtheorem{example}[theorem]{Example}
\newtheorem{exercise}[theorem]{Exercise}
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{notation}[theorem]{Notation}
\newtheorem{problem}[theorem]{Problem}
\newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}
\newtheorem{remark}[theorem]{Remark}
\newtheorem{solution}[theorem]{Solution}
\newtheorem{summary}[theorem]{Summary}
\newenvironment{proof}[1][Proof]{\noindent\textbf{#1.} }{\ \rule{0.5em}{0.5em}}
\makeatletter
\makeatother
\geometry{left=1in,right=1in,top=1.00in,bottom=1.0in}
%\setcounter{secnumdepth}{2}

\makeatletter
\if@twoside \setcounter{page}{4} \else \setcounter{page}{2} \fi
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\begin{titlepage}
\vspace*{\fill}
\begin{center}

{\Large\uppercase{\bfseries Title of Dissertation}}

\vspace{6.25cm}
{First Last Name} \\ [5pt]
\vspace{4cm}
{Submitted to the faculty of the University Graduate School}\\[5pt]
{in partial fulfillment of the requirement for the degree}\\[5pt]
{Doctor of Philosophy}\\[5pt]
{in the Department of Economics,}\\[5pt]
\vfill
{July 2015}
\end{center}
\end{titlepage}

\begin{center}
\renewcommand{\thepage}{\roman{page}}
{Accepted by the Graduate Faculty in partial\\
fulfillment of the requirements for the degree of Doctor of\\
Philosophy}\\[8cm]

\raggedright{ Doctoral Committee}
\vspace{1cm}

\raggedleft{\makebox[2.5in]{\hrulefill}}\\
\raggedleft{Committee Member 1, Ph.D.}\\[1.5cm]

\makebox[2.5in]{\hrulefill}\\
\raggedleft{Committee Member 2, Ph.D.}\\[1.5cm]

\makebox[2.5in]{\hrulefill}\\
\raggedleft{Committee Member 3, Ph.D.}\\[1.5cm]

\makebox[2.5in]{\hrulefill}\\
\raggedleft{Committee Member 4, Ph.D.}\\[1.5cm]

\raggedright{July 21st, 2015}%
\end{center}

\begin{center}
\vspace*{\fill}

Copyright \copyright \, \the\year\\
\vspace{0.5cm}
{Name} \\ [5pt]
\end{center}

\begin{center}

\vspace{4cm}

First Last Name\\ 
\vspace{0.5cm}
{\uppercase{Title}}\\ 

\vspace{1cm}


This paper examines ...
\vspace{1cm}

\raggedleft{\makebox[2in]{\hrulefill}}\\
\raggedleft{Committee Member 1, Ph.D.}\\[0.7cm]

\makebox[2in]{\hrulefill}\\
\raggedleft{Committee Member 2 Ph.D.}\\[0.7cm]

\makebox[2in]{\hrulefill}\\
\raggedleft{Committee Member 3, Ph.D.}\\[0.7cm]

\makebox[2in]{\hrulefill}\\
\raggedleft{Committee Member 4, Ph.D.}\\[0.7cm]

\end{center}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}

\tableofcontents
\clearpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\chapter{chapter1}
\lipsum[1-15]
\chapter{chapter2}
\lipsum[1-15]
\chapter{chapter3}
\lipsum[1-15]
%\input{chapter1}
%\input{chapter2}
%\input{chapter3}
%\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I'm in debt to all of you. And I apologize for the code's lack of  cleanliness, I've been accumulating packages over the years. Thanks again!